# Running Jboss 7 using different config folder under standalone-servers

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm used to jboss 5 deployment schemes where i use this command to deploy:

```
D:\jboss5\bin\run.bat -c ZZZ
```

which will deploy whatever in the **jboss5\server\ZZZ** folder

I have this structure on my jboss7:

```
D:\jboss7\
+standalone-servers
++ZZZ
+++modules
```

when i try to run jboss7 like this:

```
D:\jboss7\bin\standalone-servers.bat -c ZZZ
```

it complains with the following:

> org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module
>   org.jboss.as.standalone:main is not found in local module loader
>   @7559ec47 (roots: D:\jboss7\standalone-servers\modules)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
>     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:204)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:262)

how to tell jboss7 to look for the right configuration that resides in the folder ZZZ?

appreciate for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the base directory for a standalone JBoss EAP 6 / JBoss AS 7 instance is `${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone`

You can override this by supplying `-Djboss.server.base.dir=ZZZ`

You need to create `ZZZ/configuration` and `ZZZ/deployment` directories, and 
place your `standalone.xml` file in `ZZZ/configuration`, then start jboss using the option.

```
standalone.bat -Djboss.server.base.dir=path_to_ZZZ
```

If your JBoss configuration file is not called `standalone.xml` then you will also need to add

```
-Dtarget.appserver.configfile=my_standalone_config.xml
```

The JBoss instance base directory does not need to be within the `${JBOSS_HOME}` subdirectory tree. In fact it is better to keep it somewhere separate as it allows you to update / reinstall JBOSS binaries without overwriting your configuration files.

The `modules` folder should remain within `${JBOSS_HOME}`

So if your `${JBOSS_HOME}` were `c:\jboss7` it would look something like

```
C:\jboss7
+bin
+modules
+standalone <- not used!
... etc

c:\standalone-servers
+ZZZ
++configuration
+++standalone.xml
++deployments
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is your jboss runtime is corrupt. Reason for

```
**org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.standalone:main
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:224)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:341)**
```

is that jboss-eap-6.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\server\main package is missing inside your jboss directory. This package contains jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar and module.xml which are essential to run jboss server.